# What activity does this "don't do this in a Thai taxi" image refer to?

Tags: thailand, regulations, identify-this, taxis

The recent question [Do taxi colors matter in Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185379/59997) links to Amazing Planet's March 14, 2014 [Bangkok’s Multi-Colored Taxis](https://www.amusingplanet.com/2014/03/bangkoks-multi-colored-taxis.html) which includes a reproduction of the image shown and credited below.

I think I know what all of these "don'ts" refer to except the one on the far left, shown separately cropped, zooomed and sharpened.

**Question:** What activity does this "don't do this in a Thai taxi" image refer to?

[image: cropped, zoomed, sharpened from Adam Bowers' 2011 Flickr photo "forbidden taxi" https://www.flickr.com/photos/ill_dawg/6807960308/in/photostream/]

[image: Adam Bowers' 2011 Flickr photo "forbidden taxi" https://www.flickr.com/photos/ill_dawg/6807960308/in/photostream/]

**source:** Adam Bowers' 2011 Flickr photo "forbidden taxi" https://www.flickr.com/photos/ill_dawg/6807960308/in/photostream/

Comment: No cattle/sheep/goats carried in the taxi

Comment: What's the second one from the right, next to no-smoking…? No… chestnuts?

Comment: @deceze No durians, a famously stinky fruit.  Me, I'm more intrigued by what exactly is going on in the 3rd from the left.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Ah, yes, the fruit from hell. The other one is clearly *No Brazilian jiu-jitsu*.

Comment: @Midavalo since all of the others are straigh-forward, diagrammatic and not stylized, I'm not sure the googly-eyed, oversized head and horns illustration is a no-nonsense representation of livestock. There may be more context here.

Comment: It means that they won't take you to the local Freemason lodge.

Comment: @lambshaanxy: I think it might be "Don't deliver a baby." But I have no idea how that could *possibly* be such a common problem that they felt the need to make a sign for it, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I think third from left is "no sex". Which... yeah. Can't believe they felt the need to point it out.

Comment: @Martha some people get really skewed ideas of what's normal from watching adult content.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Sex in moving vehicles is as old as vehicles, both for sex work and "spontaneous combustion" between couples. [Hugh grant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Grant#Legal_issues) got caught back in 1985 (though it was his own parked vehicle). By the angle of legs we can tell one is probably a [Ladyboy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathoey) making a bit of money to help pay for her brother's school or her parent's health care or for her [gender-affirming surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathoey#Requirements_to_confirm_eligibility_for_gender-affirming_surgery).

Answer (score 41):

From [Reddit](https://redd.it/zgn7me), the symbol represents a [water buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_buffalo), and the Thai word for buffalo also means idiot, so the sign means no idiot / don't be an idiot. Ask the taxi driver if that sign means that the car is a self-driving car.

Comment: I have a feeling that asking the driver might also be one of the don'ts. Perhaps it's also covered by the same symbol :-)

Comment: This is reminiscent to some South Asia country which uses the cow as the "stupid animal", whereas some Western countries use the donkey.

Comment: @Clockwork I wonder whether any countries use humans as the stupid animal.

Comment: @TooTea yes that's why I use ride-sharing apps.

Comment: @Clockwork, so you’re saying that an appropriate translation would be “don’t be an ass”?

Comment: @CarstenS I was just saying that one of these countries have a saying, which is: "stupid like a cow", which means some countries use other animals as the equivalent of the donkey in some Western countries.

Comment: @Clockwork, I was trying to make a donkey joke.

Comment: Oh yes, putting the prohibition sign solves that problem. Sounds riiiiight.

Comment: @SJuan76 I have a photo somewhere of a similar sign in a taxi in Taipei - it's essentially "no vomiting". Similarly questionable efficacy?

Comment: @uhoh About as efficacious as countries/jurisdictions where it’s [illegal to die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibition_of_dying).